# Error opening PDF file with fileOpener2 in Ionic v3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am trying to open a PDF file in my Ionic application and get the following error:

> Error opening file Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

What the application does is that it receives a file in base64 format, transforms it to BLOB and then downloads it to the application directory, until this process all goes perfectly, this is the path it writes the file:

> file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/Informativo%202019_10_20%20e%2021

Returns that:

```
FileEntry {
isFile: true, 
isDirectory: false, 
name: "Informativo 2019_10_20 e 21", 
fullPath: "/Informativo 2019_10_20 e 21", filesystem: FileSystem…}
filesystem: FileSystem
fullPath: "/Informativo 2019_10_20 e 21"
isDirectory: false
isFile: true
name: "Informativo 2019_10_20 e 21"
nativeURL: "file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/Informativo%202019_10_20%20e%2021"
```

**Then you run File Opener to open and the error pops:**

```
this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, fileName, DataBlob, contentType).then((success) => {  
        console.log("File Writed Successfully", success);
        //Method showing error below
        this.fileOpener.open(success.toURL(), this.contentType)
            .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
            .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
    }).catch((err) => {  
        console.log("Error Occured While Writing File", err);
    })
```

I also have this file that I saw in other similar questions: **opener_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles -->
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- cordova.file.dataDirectory -->
    <files-path name="files" path="." />
    <!-- cordova.file.cacheDirectory -->
    <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
    <!-- cordova.file.externalDataDirectory -->
    <external-files-path name="external-files" path="." />
    <!-- cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory -->
    <external-cache-path name="external-cache" path="." />
    <!-- cordova.file.externalRootDirectory -->
    <external-path name="external" path="." />
</paths>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: `Then you run File Opener to open and the error pops.` I think you should show the used code. The rest is not important anymore.

Comment: @blackapps I updated it to show the code that pops the error first.

Comment: You are not using `filePath` and 'fileName'in fileOpener(). What should this fileOpener() do? Please explain.

Comment: Are you trying to let the user select one of the pdf viewers on your device to let it display the pdf file?

Comment: `Error opening file Attempt to invoke virtu` And which app is displaying this error message. Yours? Or the by the user selected app?

Comment: @blackapps `this.file.writeFile` is a method to write the file into `dataDirectory`, it's using  `filePath` and `fileName` to do that, and It completes succesfull, after I have the file written I try to open it with fileOpener2, this plugin is supposed to open any file with the default viewer of the user. 
This is my app.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file-opener/

Comment: You have saved the file to a private directory of your app. No other app has access to it. So it makes no sense to tell that path to another app. Save the file to a place that is visible for other apps too. And even if you have done that you probably need to use a file provider to serve the file. Once you need a file provider you could leave the pdf file in apps private directory too.

Comment: @blackapps This app opens the file that it is in his own directory. I didn't understand that logic. It's not trying to access the file from some other app.

Comment: `this plugin is supposed to open any file with the default viewer of the user. This is my app. ` So your app tries to display its own pdf file. For what do you need a plugin then? Foe what do you need openFile() ? You could better start your vieuwer directly with that path.

Comment: That's the  ionic native file opener, I don't know any other way to do it in Ionic...